# using static method on javascript class

Tags: javascript, express, model-view-controller

I am concerned about which one is more faster. Should I use create a new object from a class and use that object or use class with static methods.

```
export default class AuthServices { 
    static async login (data) {}
    static async register (data) {}
}
```

The above code used static method and I can access `login` and `register` function by calling class name first. Should I get rid of static and create an object on the file that is going to call these functions.

Comment: No point in creating an instance of some object just to call a method that doesn't use that object.  So, `static` would be preferred.  This is entirely equivalent to a plain object with two properties on it.  `static` is just another means of declaring the same thing.  It also allows that their may be other code that instantiates the class too and uses an instantiated object, but that is not required.  One can use just `static` methods by themselves and it will as efficient as declaring a plain object with the methods on it.

Comment: Also worrying about whether a static class method or a plain object method is faster is definitely premature optimization.  You have much more important things to worry about, especially since they are the same internal implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use an object literal for AuthServics instead of a class.

```
export default const AuthServices =  { 
      login: async (data) {}
      register: async (data) {}
}
```

If you want to use class then use static methods and do not instantiate from class.
Access the methods like this

```
AuthServices.login()
```

There is no need to create multiple copies of these methods in memory.

Comment: This does the same thing as using `static` on a class.  They literally generate and execute the same code - no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to implement `AuthService` as a singleton with a static method to get the instance.
(Since you would want to have a global access to this service)

```
class AuthService {

  constructor() {
    if (!AuthService._instance) {
      AuthService._instance = this;
    }
    return AuthService._instance;
  }

  static getInstance() {
    return this._instance;
  }

  async login(data) {
   //Implementation
  }

  async register(data) {
  //Implementation
  }
}
```

To access it you would do something like this:

```
const authService = AuthService.getInstance();

authService.register();
authService.login();
```

Comment: Why do you need a singleton just to access two static methods?  That's overkill for the problem they show.  All the OP shows is two static methods.